# function targeting only clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page with several accordions, which are working, but the js is affecting all accordions and not only the clicked on accordion as it should be. how does the JS needs to be changed that only the "clicked on" accordion changes?

here's the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');

    jQuery('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    jQuery("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})

})
```

and here one of the accordeons:

```
<div class="mytabcontainer">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab-link current" data-tab="A-1">BUTTON A</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="B-1">BUTTON B</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="C-1">BUTTON C</li>
</ul>
<div id="A-1" class="tab-content current">
content A
</div>
<div id="B-1" class="tab-content">
content B
</div>
<div id="C-1" class="tab-content">
content C
</div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you select all accordions in the page.

You want to do something like this:

```
jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');

    jQuery(this).closest('.mytabcontainer').find('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    jQuery(this).closest('.mytabcontainer').find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    jQuery("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```

Comment: whoohooo! thanks a lot! i knew i had to use closest but that was all regarding my "skills"... thanks !!!!